# Can a shareholder who makes a tender offer vote for the offer?

Tags: stocks

Suppose I own 30% of a company and make a tender offer to buy all shares (e.g., at 120% of the current stock price) and thereby make the company private.  Also, suppose the board of directors supports my proposal and places it on the next proxy vote.

Do my 30% of shares count for that proxy vote? Or, is it effectively like only 70% of the shares exist and a majority of that 70% is needed?

Intuitively, I would think that my shares should be excluded...this becomes more evident if I change 30% to 51% above.  But, I can't find a reference.

Comment: `Intuitively, I would think that my shares should be excluded`  Why?  I don't think that's intuitive at all...

Comment: Why would it go to a vote? Wouldn't it be up to the other shareholders whether to sell to you or not?

Answer (score -1):

While I dont have the answer to your actual question, it seemed malformed.  A tender offer is an offer to receive more shares, usually at a higher price than usual, from current shareholders rather than from the company.  It would not turn a company private.  I believe the vote you are thinking of would be to do a reverse stock split.

https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answersgoprivhtm.html

was one of my references and it reminded me as well that different states have different shareholders rights, so you would need to be more specific, but I am 100% sure the information you are looking for are available via government documents.

Comment: No, [tender offer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tender_offer) is the right terminology for offering to buy the outstanding shares and take a company private. Nothing to do with a reverse split. In fact, the document you link to explicitly refers to a tender offer (first bullet point).